# mediaelement.js playing sound not mp4 video on chrome.

Tags: google-chrome, mp4, mediaelement.js

on all browsers follows video plays but not on chrome.

```
 http://www.cool-mobile-stuff.com/view.php?id=14
```

is there any solution? The mimetype is fine. its video/mp4 not sure what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

later i came to know that mp4 is not supported in chrome. The chrome support .webm format for videos in html5. I converted video to .webm using free converter winff and added

```
 <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm">
```

to my video tag and it worked fine. Hope it can help others.

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome supports MP4; it's Chromium that does not: http://www.chromium.org/audio-video

I had a similar issue to this (except video wouldn't play at all) and found that removing the call to mediaelement.play() enabled it to work.

I still don't know why, the MediaElement demo works fine for me...! Yet I can set my own page up almost exactly the same and run it from the same server with the exact same video and it doesn't work.